# SQL: Left join issue that I can't seem to figure out

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

here's the statement:

```sql
SELECT order.order_id, order.member_id, order.date_ordered, coupon.coupon_name, coupon.coupon_type, coupon.coupon_amount
FROM order
LEFT JOIN coupon
ON order.coupon_id = coupon.coupon_id
```

And here's the MySQL error:

```sql
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order LEFT JOIN coupon ON order.coupon_id = coupon.coupon_id' at line 2
```

Both tables have a `coupon_id`. I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I guess "order" should be in backticks since it's a keyword

Comment: maybe ORDER keyword makes problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`order` is a reserved word, you should escape it:

```
SELECT `order`.order_id, `order`.member_id, `order`.date_ordered, 
        coupon.coupon_name, coupon.coupon_type, coupon.coupon_amount
FROM `order`
LEFT JOIN coupon
ON `order`.coupon_id = coupon.coupon_id
```

Comment: God ... how dumb of me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

order is a reserved word.  You need to "escape" it.

For MySQL, you can use the back tick (`) to escape a column name, especially if it happens to be the same as a reserved word.

```
SELECT * FROM `order`
```

As an aside, SQL Server uses the square brackets [] to escape column names.

```
SELECT * FROM [order]
```

Answer (score 2):

Order is a reserved word.

Place it in backquotes or name your table something else.

Answer (score 0):

`order` is a reserved keyword.  You need to specify it as

```
`order`
```

for your query to work